# Register many value converts in one command in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have in my app many value converts and custom element serving all the app.

```
resources/value-converters/1.js,
resources/value-converters/2.js,
resources/value-converters/3.js,

resources/elements/1.js,
resources/elements/2.js,
resources/elements/3.js,
```

Is there a way to register all the converts and the elements to global resources in one command? I mean not adding them manually one by one with the global resource.

Thanks...

Comment: Ok, I moved all value converters to a folder and added the index.js there I registered all the converters. in the main.js I added this folder as feature. Still will be nice if there is an idea to add all the resources in the index.js dynamically and not write them one by one.